# php5-mysql depends on php5 but cannot find it

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

my Goal is to set up a Vagrant Box containing some kind of http Server (lighttpd atm), PHP 5.2, some SQL Database (MySQL) and PhpMyAdmin.

I'm using a trusty64 box and to meet the requirement of PHP 5.2 i've imported an old ubuntu repository.

Here are my files:

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3306

  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic main'"

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "start.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.options = "--verbose"
  end
end
```

puppet/manifests/start.pp

```
# Puppet configurations

Exec { path =>  [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

include aptupdate
include lighttpd
include php52
#include mysql
#include phpmyadmin
```

puppet/modules/aptupdate/manifests/init.pp

```
class aptupdate {
  exec {"apt-get-update":
    command => "apt-get update",
    path => "/usr/bin"
  }
}
```

puppet/modules/aptupdate/manifests/init.pp

```
class lighttpd{
  package {
    'lighttpd':
    ensure => installed
  }

  service {
    'lighttpd':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => Package['lighttpd']
  }
}
```

puppet/modules/aptupdate/manifests/init.pp

```
class php52{

  $phpversion = "5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6"

  package { "php5":
    ensure => $phpversion,
  }

  package { "php5-common":
    ensure => $phpversion,
    require => Package["php5"],
  }

  package { "php5-mysql":
    ensure => $phpversion,
    require => Package["php5", "php5-common"],
  }

}
```

**The Problem**

I've added a MySQL module that was fine, and finally a PhpMyAdmin Module as you can see in start.pp. PhpMyAdmin was asking for php5-mysql as an dependency, so i've added it to php5/init.pp. This leads to a php5-common dependency of php5-mysql, also added by me. Afterwards it required php5, so i've added it to the require => Package column.
But now, the first Requirement is asked again and i don't know what to change to succeed with the installation of php 5.2

Here is the Error Message

```
==> default: Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install php5-mysql=5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
==> default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
==> default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
==> default: or been moved out of Incoming.
==> default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
==> default:
==> default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> default:  php5-mysql : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
==> default:                        phpapi-20060613
==> default: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Php52/Package[php5-mysql]/ensure: change from purged to 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install php5-mysql=5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
==> default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
==> default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
==> default: or been moved out of Incoming.
==> default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
==> default:
==> default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> default:  php5-mysql : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
==> default:                        phpapi-20060613
==> default: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For Hints i'd be very grateful

Comment: Side note: I _**strongly**_ urge you to use a newer version of PHP. Whatever reasons you think you have for using version 5.2 probably aren't good enough. [PHP 5.2 is _**ancient**_](http://php.net/eol.php) and hasn't received security patches for years.

Comment: was expecting this kind of comment, forgot to mention it in my question and i agree with you. but nethertheless making the old software run again on my development machine is an essential part of upgrading it.

Comment: I suspect this may be due to conflicts between the Trusty and Karmic package repositories. You could build your VM using Karmic (though no pre-built Vagrant boxes seem to be available for it due to its age), or you could build PHP from source.

Comment: All else notwithstanding, with your declarations, Puppet should have applied `Package[php5]`, version 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6 before attempting to install the same version of `Package[php5-mysql]`.  Had applying the former package failed, Puppet should not have even attempted to apply the latter, but when it *does* apply the latter, it does not see php5 installed.  Something funny is going on here, possibly involving other packages beyond those you named.  I suggest turning on `--debug` logging in the agent to try to figure out what's happening with php5.